# Are submodules of free modules free?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Are all submodules of free modules free? I would like a reference to a proof or counterexample please.

Comment: I won't downvote since someone already answered, but I don't think is appropriate for MO.

Comment: Another example you might be interested in is take the ring R = ZxZ. Certainly R as a module over itself is free; take Z as a submodule. It's clearly not free, since it's not the direct sum of copies of R, yet it is projective.

Comment: +1, since the answers made lemonade (e.g. KConrad's reference for Pete Clark, in the comments).

Comment: @JasonPolak When you say take $\mathbb Z$ as a submodule, I take it you mean $\mathbb Z \times \{0\}$.  Why wouldn't this be a principal ideal of $R$ generated by $([1,0])$, and thus $[1,0]$ form a basis for the submodule $\mathbb Z \times 0$?

Comment: @TravisBemrose Trouble is that the $R$-module map $R \to \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ sending the identity $1 \in R$ (i.e. $(1, 1)$) to $(1, 0)$ is not an isomorphism, since $(0, 1)$ gets sent to $0$.

Comment: Ah, so then the scalar $(0,1)$ times the module element $(1,0)$ is the zero element, so this is a nonzero linear combination that gives zero, so the single element $(1,0)$ is a dependent set, and not a basis (even though it can generate the entire submodule)?

Comment: @TravisBemrose That's right.

Comment: @TravisBemrose: principal ideals generated by zero divisors are not free....

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Вот общий пример: неглавной идеал в кольце $A$.  Кольцо $A$ -- свободный $A$-модуль.  Идеал в кольце -- подмодуль, а он тоже свободный $A$-модуль только в случае, что он главной идеал:  ненулевые элементы $a$ и $b$ в кольце удовлетворяют нетривиальному $A$-линейному соотношению $c_1a + c_2b = 0$, где $c_1 = b$ и $c_2 = -a$, поэтому если существует базис, то мощность является одним.

Comment: To paraphrase: *"An ideal in a ring is a submodule of a free module over that ring. Any two elements $a$ and $b$ of the ideal satisfy the relation $(b)a+(-a)b=0$, so if the ideal has a basis (i.e. is a free module), it must be principal."*

Comment: To continue the paraphrase: "Therefore any nonprincipal ideal, as a module over the ring, is a counterexample." 

Principal ideals can be counterexamples too if the ring isn't a domain: if a is a zero divisor (and not 0 itself) then the principal ideal (a) is not a free module.

Comment:  Дорогой колега, откуда вы так хорошо пишете по-русски? Во всяком случае, поздравляю! Кстати, отвечать по-русски - прекрасная идея: я только что проголосовал за вас

Comment: Funny! The last few words should read: поэтому если существует базис, то он мощности один.

Comment: यह तो मुझे भी आता है|

Comment: Beh, mi sembra giusto.

Comment: Hvaða rugl er þetta. Ef spurningin er á ensku þá á svarið að vera á ensku!

Comment: Grétar: Slappe spørsmål får åpenbart besvares som man vil.

Comment: This has gotten out of control. =P

Comment: @JonBeardsley: Tout à fait, mais c'est un bel hommage à la diversité de nos langues.

Comment: @ACL ah oui, sans doute, desolee. mais je parle seulement l'anglais (as you can probably tell). :-(

Comment: witzige Kommentare:D

Comment: Onay oremay ommentscay, easeplay.

Comment: @GMRA, מסכים איתך שמן הראוי להשיב באנגלית אם השאלה באנגלית.

Comment: ¿Llego tarde a comentar en español?

Comment: 本当に申し訳ありませんが、わかりません。

Answer (score 21):

No, for a general ring, yes for PIDs. Take as a counter example the ring of integers mod 4 as a module over it self.

Comment: The first sentence is correct, but the second is not: the integers mod 4 is not a counterexample. Any ring A is a free A-module since {1} is a basis: it spans and has no nontrivial A-linear relations.  

Comment: He probably meant "take 2ℤ/4 as a module over ℤ/4."

Comment: Yes, 2Z/4Z as a Z/4Z-module is a counterexample, but what was suggested was Z/4Z "as a module over itself". That's what I was writing in response to.

Comment: I thought he meant, "take Z/4 over itself as an example of a free module that has a non-free submodule."

Comment: Ah, of course!  Silly me.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb to admit my ignorance here, but: what is a standard reference that shows that a submodule of a free module over a PID is free?  (Note that I did not say finitely generated.)

Comment: A reference is Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra, pp. 650--651.  The proof uses the axiom of choice in the form of the well-ordering principle.

Comment: Hungerford also proves this fact in his Algebra using the well-ordering principle. He calls it a "sketch" but it is fairly complete. 

Comment: This is also Theorem 5.1 in chapter 1 of 
Hilton and Stammbach, A Course in Homological Algebra, 
Graduate Texts in Mathematics 4.

Answer (score 11):

For any (unitary commutative) ring $A$, the following are equivalent: (i) submodules of free $A$-modules are free, (ii) any ideal is free as $A$-module, (iii) the ring $A$ is a principal ideal domain. The proof is already clear form the above discussion. Therefore, if counterexamples exist, conterexamples must exists as ideals of the ring. As for the counterexamples already given here, (1) the ideal $(X,Y)$ of the polynomial ring $k[X,Y]$ is not even flat, as noted by Robin Chapman, (2) the ideal $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not flat, since it is generated by a non-zero nilpotent element, (3) the ideal $\mathbb{Z}\times 0$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is projective but not free, similar result holds for the ideal $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. I am trying to find an ideal $I$ of a ring $A$ such that $I$ is flat but not projective as $A$-module. Obviously, such a conterexample esists only if the ring $A$ is non-Noetherian. Maybe non-Noetherian prufer domains can work. Could someone give me such an example, i.e., to find an ideal $I$ of a ring $A$ such that $I$ is flat but not projective as $A$-module?

Comment: @Konstantin Ardakov: You are right. Thanks a lot for the detailed explaination!

Comment: See Martin's answer there (a reference to Lam's book on modules and rings): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400776/finitely-generated-flat-modules-that-are-not-projective

Answer (score 8):

Another example: let $R=k[x,y]$ where $k$ is a field.
Then $R$ is a free module over itself, and the ideal $I$
of $R$ generated by $x$ and $y$ is not only not free over $R$,
it is not even flat over $R$.

Answer (score 6):

To answer ding8191's question: let $A$ be any valuation ring of height $1$ which is not a discrete valuation ring. That is to say, let $F$ be a field and suppose that there is a function $v : F \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ such that $v(xy) = v(x) + v(y), v(1) = 0, v(0) = \infty$ and $v(x + y) \geq \min $ $\{ v(x), v(y) \}$ (thus $v$ is a valuation), such that $v(F)$ is not a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $A = \{ x \in F :v(x)\geq 0\}$ (the valuation ring of $F$).

Then the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in this ring is a direct limit of principal ideals and is therefore flat. If $\mathfrak{m}$ was projective, then it would have to be free by Kaplansky's Theorem (all projectives over any local ring are free), but since $\mathfrak{m}$ is contained in $F$ it has to have rank at most $1$, hence $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal. But this would force the valuation on $A$ to be discrete.

You can find this material in Chapter VI of Bourbaki's "Commutative Algebra" (Hermann, 1972). In particular, Lemma $1$ of $\S 3.6$ says that if $A$ is a valuation ring (in a more general sense than I defined above), then every torsion-free $A$-module is flat, and Proposition $9$ of the same subsection implies that $A$ is a discrete valuation ring whenever $A$ is a valuation ring of height $1$ with principal maximal ideal.

To give a concrete example, consider the field $F$ of [Puiseux series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) and let $A$ be its valuation ring.

Answer (score 1):

For a ring R, if e is an idempotent element diferent from zero and one, then Re is projective module which isn't free.

Comment: There exist examples of rings $R$ with a proper direct summand isomorphic to $R$ itself (as a, say, right $R$-module). The absence of this pathology is called direct finiteness of the ring and it does not come for free. Of course, this does not happen on commutative rings!