# How to explain the picturesque patterns in François Brunault's matrix?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ra.rings-and-algebras, sequences-and-series, linear-algebra

How to explain the patterns in the matrix defined in François Brunault's
answer to the question [Freeness of a Z[x] module](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133315/) depicted below? --

Choosing colors according to the highest power of 2 which divides an entry,
we can obtain for example the following pictures:

[image: A picture of resolution 512 x 512 pixels depicting the entries of François Brunault's matrix]

[image: A picture of resolution 512 x 512 pixels depicting the entries of François Brunault's matrix]

Taking instead highest power of 3 dividing an entry, we can obtain for example this picture:

[image: A picture of resolution 512 x 512 pixels depicting the entries of François Brunault's matrix]

Coloring zero entries white, negative entries red and positive entries blue
yields the following picture:

[image: A picture of resolution 512 x 512 pixels depicting the entries of François Brunault's matrix]

And finally, marking non-zero entries black and leaving zero entries blank,
the pattern looks like this:

[image: A picture of resolution 512 x 512 pixels depicting the entries of François Brunault's matrix]

**Added:** Assigning colors according to numbers of prime factors of the entries,
we can obtain the following picture:

[image: A picture of resolution 182 x 182 pixels depicting the entries of François Brunault's matrix]

**Added on June 15, 2013:** Choosing colors depending on entries (mod 47), we can obtain
the following picture (nonzero entries divisible by 47 are colored red):

[image: A picture of resolution 512 x 512 pixels depicting the entries of François Brunault's matrix]

Comment: Have you tried plotting the number of prime factors in colors? My plot:  http://s24.postimg.org/5rj4gkkat/rxdivisors.png

Comment: @Joro: Thanks. Yes, I tried also this- Though computing such picture in the same resolution
(512 x 512 pixels) as the others seems to take notably more time, so
I computed only smaller ones.
 

Comment: Factoring the matrix entries is not always easy -- the factors are
sometimes not all very small. Until line 140 of the matrix, the largest second-largest factor which occurs is 278454866719523378494429.


Comment: Primes in the matrix appear very rare.

Comment: Already squarefree entries appear relatively rare.

Comment: @Joro: I have added a picture with colors indicating numbers of prime factors. The picture shows the first 182 lines of the matrix.
The largest second-largest prime factor occurring until there is
11471706246154038875504014889 (occurring at the 5th entry of the
171th line).


Comment: Is there any pattern if you plot $M[i,j] \mod n$ for certain n?

Comment: @Joro: Yes, there also is some pattern -- I have added a picture for $n = 47$. Choosing moduli $n$ with only smallish prime factors restricts the pattern to the left side of the picture since entries further to the right are all divisible by $n$.
 

Comment: Thank you for spotting these nice patterns! Not a precise explanation, but it may not be surprising that the entries of the matrix have nice $p$-adic properties. Indeed, any generalized polynomial map (in the sense of the question you link to) extends to a map $\mathbf{Z}_p \to \mathbf{Z}_p$ which is continuous (and in fact, 1-Lipschitz).